# Multiple values selection in a desktop application

Tags: wpf, swing, ms-access, desktop-application, multiple-records

I was preparing a **MS Access based Desktop Database Application** for a **Coaching classes**. Now since **previously** the application only consisted of the **basic form based functions** including, adding new student, displaying the list of students, the fee structure and the attendance.
Now he's asked me to prepare a more dynamic application, **adding following functionalities** along with the previous,
1. A question based contents, which can be selected at one time

eg: q1
       q2
       q3
       q4

**So** **if we select q1 & q4**, **only those two** **questions should be displaying in the next sheet(wordsheet preferably)**.
Thus helping him to make a quick question paper.
I am not much familiar on how to achieve this on Ms Access. I **tried Macros**, but I couldn't find one which selects multiple questions and achieves the above task.
So i wanted to get an help on this, is there a way to achieve this on MS Access or is there some other technology which might help me on this?

Comment: listboxes are capable of multi selection. you can try listbox with for each selected.item and go from there

Comment: How are these questions stored? Are they records in a table (eg. with fields question_number, question_text etc.)?

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys. Well to start of, the question bank is still not a part of the application yet. So i can do, two things 1. create a form comprising of each of the above attributes along with the options, which i assume would consume ample amount of time, since the question bank's huge. 2. Migrate the whole application to swing application or wpf. So my next question, which tool would be easier to achieve it in that case?